# xbox achievement / trophy statistics?

Tags: data-request

Each Xbox game has certain challenges called "Achievements and Trophies". When one is achieved, a pop up appears on screen notifying the player. Along with the notification that the achievement as been made, the notification also displays the % of other purchasers of that game who also got the achievement.

Is this data (a list of game + achievement + % of players who achieve) publicly available somewhere (preferably as an API)?